# Solve discrete Algebratic Riccati Equation without doing the inverse?

Tags: control-theory, optimal-control, linear-control

Is it possible to solve discrete Algebraic Riccati Equations without doing any inverse?

$$X_{k+1} = A^T X_k A -(A^T X_k B)(R + B^T X_k B)^{-1}(B^T X_k A) + Q$$
$$L =(B^T X_{k+1} B + R)^{-1}(B^TX_{k+1}A)$$

Assume that $k = 0, ... , n$

Or do I need to use LUP-factorication to solve the inverse?

Comment: A small note: the algebraic Riccati equation is for the stationary solution, so $X_{k+1}=X_k$. What you consider could be called a Riccati difference equation.

Comment: @KwinvanderVeen Yes, I just changed the equation. I hope you understand? Is there any reason for me to solve this equation, or should I solve it with a least square solution instead?